# É possivel usar a função DATENAME() com o formato datetime do mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, atom

Boas como vão?
estou aqui com uma dúvida estoua  criar um website em HTML e PHP e queria mostrar uns dados da base de dados mysql, eu tenho um campo que é autoincrement que é o datetime e com este campo queria mostrar a data em si mesmo e depois tambem mostrar o dia da semana tipo (SEGUNDA,TERÇA...) só que eu ja fiz 1001 pesquisas e estou a fazer exatamente como eles dizem e a mim não funciona...
Será que podiam dar aí uma ajuda?

código:

```
$sql = "SELECT DATENAME(weekday, data), temperature, humidity FROM sensor WHERE `data` < (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: Tem certeza de que a função é `DATENAME`? Não seria `DAYNAME(data)`? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda amigo! relamente era mesmo isso... outroas diziam para acrescentar weekday mas esta perfeito!